# Red Error fx:id

Tags: javafx

Подскажите почему когда я присваиваю ID у меня все уходит в ошибку?

[image: Скрин]

[image: Код контроллера]

Comment: Покажите код контроллера с полем этого элемента такого же названия

Comment: Добавил скрин кода контроллера

Comment: @YevgenyShevchenko Когда просят показать код, просят именно код, а не скриншот ide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Импорты у вас `awt`, а нужны `javafx.scene.control`